# Differentiating between regular and irregular shaped blobs

Tags: python, matlab, image-processing, language-agnostic, computer-vision

I have a set of connected blobs, and I would like to distinguish the more regular (`a`, `c` and `d` in the figure) from the more irregular ones, like `b`.

I tried using the convolved area (putting a threshold on blob_area/convolved_blob_area), [shape factor and roundness](http://www.empix.com/NE%20HELP/functions/glossary/morphometric_param.htm) but none of them works well to distinguish between `d` and a banana-like shape. Which parameters would you suggest to use? Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One idea that came into my mind was that, you can use `number of corners` per `size of blob` to determine the `regularity/irregularity`. The test results seem to comply with our hypothesis too. Here's the code -

```
im = imread(input_image_path);
bw= im2bw(im);

%// Parameter for cutting into four slices into the third dimsensions 
%// corresponding to the four objects
common_width = 270; 

%// Threshold to decide between regular and irregular ones
factor1_th = 0.01;

bw1 = bw(:,1:common_width*floor(size(bw,2)/common_width)); %// Cropped image
objs =reshape(bw1,size(bw1,1),common_width,[]);%//Objects stored as dim3 slices
for objc=1:size(objs,3) %// Object counter
    disp(['-------------- Processing Obj #' num2str(objc)]);
    obj = objs(:,:,objc);
    corners = corner(obj);
    factor1 = size(corners,1)/nnz(obj)
    if factor1 > factor1_th
        disp('This is an irregular one.'); %//'
    else
        disp('This is a regular one.'); %//'
    end
end
```

Output -

```
-------------- Processing Obj #1
factor1 =
    0.0050
This is a regular one.
-------------- Processing Obj #2
factor1 =
    0.0109
This is an irregular one.
-------------- Processing Obj #3
factor1 =
    0.0052
This is a regular one.
-------------- Processing Obj #4
factor1 =
    0.0078
This is a regular one.
```

If anyone is interested in running the code, here's the input image that has the symbols a,b,c,d removed -

[image]

Link - https://i.stack.imgur.com/uPpUU.jpg

Comment: A quick and dirty possible solution: calculate `perimeter/area` and put a threshold on that.

Comment: @albus_c I did think about that, but that way you would have elongated objects like the banana and straight-thin rods considered as irregular ones and I don't think you want that or do you?

Comment: I agree with you. I think counting corners is much better as a solution!